# How to detect the last element of an array to prevent punctuation Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am passing data into an array via .onclick and then running it through a for loop to append the names. I need to output in a specific format ie. `1. John, 2. Paul, 3. George, 4. Ringo`. My struggle is having no comma displayed on the last element. It has been explained that I am supposed to use a if statement to check when JavaScript is looking at the last element in the array and then not display the comma somehow?
Sorry if this question is worded terrible or short of data this is my first post on stackoverflow and I am very new to programming. Any and all help/ suggestions is appreciated.

```
var showList = function()
{
HYUTS = "";

for (var i=0; i < BeatlesArray.length; i++) {
    HYUTS += i + 1 + ". " + BeatlesArray[i] + " ";
}
$("list").innerHTML = HYUTS;    
}
```

Reason as to why I did not add this section of my .js is because I know its incorrect and not producing what I want.

Comment: Add the code, both HTML, JS. Please see [ask] with [mcve]

Comment: You can use `join` to get commas in between but not after.

Comment: Do you want a comma after the last element of an array? That would be improper syntax.

Comment: If this is a string than just do `str+=',';`

Comment: The answer is to use an `if` statement to avoid the comma after the last element.

Comment: I would use join. To handle your exact case: `['john','paul','george','ringo'].map(function(curVal,idx){return ((idx+1)+'. '+curVal)}).join(', ');`

Comment: Sorry for the bad clarity @Max Mastalerz. I want no comma at the end.

Comment: Actually, I see you seem to be directed to use the `if` - in that case, you could just add the `if (i < (BeatlesArray.length-1)) HYUTS+=', ';` as the second line inside your `for` block.

Comment: barry-johnson that solved it thank you so much! Is there anyway you can add that below so I can check it as solved. (sorry I dont know this site at all yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the for loop that you've written here:

```
for (var i=0; i < BeatlesArray.length; i++) {
    HYUTS += i + 1 + ". " + BeatlesArray[i] + " ";
}
```

It seems like you want to concatenate a comma after this line each time you loop over a new Beatles band member, but NOT if you are currently concatenating the last Beatle in the band.

So, add an if statement to check that condition, and only add the comma if it is not true:

```
for (var i=0; i < BeatlesArray.length; i++) {
    HYUTS += i + 1 + ". " + BeatlesArray[i];
    if (i < (BeatlesArray.length - 1)) {
        HYUTS += ", ";
    }
}
```

When i is equal to the length of the array (minus 1 because the array is zero indexed), you have reached the last element. So, by checking that i is LESS than the last element, you know that this is the proper time to append the comma to the String you are building.

Answer (score 2):

One option: always prepend the comma, rather than optionally appending it.

```
var Beatles = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"],
    HYUTS = '1. ' + Beatles[0]

for (var i = 1; i < Beatles.length; i++)
  HYUTS += ', ' + (i+1) + '. ' + Beatles[i]

console.log(HYUTS)
```

Output:

```
1. John, 2. Paul, 3. George, 4. Ringo
```

Comment: Question for you Julian, would this still work if the Array was not pre-populated?

Comment: @HYUTS, if at some point you are saying "I want to process an array of more than zero elements", then you can always take off the first element of that array and then loop over the rest.  If you never reach that point, but are only ever sometimes receiving an additional element that you'd like to add to a string, then there's no need to loop at all, and you must always test to see if you need to add a comma or not.  In the second case, it hardly matters if you prepend or append the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Although as a general practice, I like @Julian Fondren's answer better, because it avoids having a conditional inside a loop (and thus has better performance), because you wanted to use the `if` statement, the code you are looking for is something like the following:

```
var showList = function()
{
    HYUTS = "";

   for (var i=0; i < BeatlesArray.length; i++) {
      HYUTS += i + 1 + ". " + BeatlesArray[i] + " ";
      if (i < (BeatlesArray.length-1))
           HYUTS+=', ';
   }
   $("list").innerHTML = HYUTS;    
}
```